# Print output from an external command and save to a variable in perl

Tags: perl

In perl, how do you run an external process showing output *as it happens*, and save that output to a variable?

I'd like to use IPC::Run3, but it's not required.

Eg, this won't work because it doesn't take multiple handles:

```
use IPC::Run3;
my $out;
my @cmd = qw!/usr/bin/tail -f /tmp/writetothis!;
run3( \@cmd, undef, [ <STDOUT>, \$out ] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, it would seem you could use the following:

```perl
use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 );

my $out = '';
run3 \@cmd,
   \undef,
   sub {
      $out .= $_[0];
      print $_[0];
   };
```

But the callback is only called once the child completes, even if you disable buffering in the child. (Full demonstration below.) That means you might as well have used the following:

```perl
use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 );

my $out = '';
run3 \@cmd, \undef, \$out;
print $out;
```

If that's a problem, then you could use the virtually identical but more powerful [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run).
(Full demonstration below.)

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

my $out = '';
run \@cmd,
   \undef,
   sub {
      $out .= $_[0];
      print $_[0];
   };
```

This is still slave to any buffering performed by the child. If that's a problem, you could use `>pty>` to try to convince the child to avoid buffering.
(Full demonstration below.)

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

my $out = '';
run \@cmd,
   \undef,
   '>pty>' => sub {
      $out .= $_[0];
      print $_[0];
   };
```

---

Full demonstration of IPC::Run3 solution:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 );

my @cmd = ( $^X => ( -e => <<'__EOS__' ) );
   use Time::HiRes qw( sleep );

   $| = 1;

   for (1..10) {
      print "$_\n";
      sleep(0.2);
   }
__EOS__

my $out = '';
run3 \@cmd,
   \undef,
   sub {
      $out .= $_[0];
      print $_[0];
   };

say "[$out]";
```

---

Full demonstration of IPC::Run solution:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use IPC::Run qw( run );

my @cmd = ( $^X => ( -e => <<'__EOS__' ) );
   use Time::HiRes qw( sleep );

   $| = 1;

   for (1..10) {
      print "$_\n";
      sleep(0.2);
   }
__EOS__

my $out = '';
run \@cmd,
   \undef,
   sub {
      $out .= $_[0];
      print $_[0];
   };

say "[$out]";
```

---

Full demonstration of IPC::Run solution with `>pty>`:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use IPC::Run qw( run );

my @cmd = ( $^X => ( -e => <<'__EOS__' ) );
   use Time::HiRes qw( sleep );

   for (1..10) {
      print "$_\n";
      sleep(0.2);
   }
__EOS__

my $out = '';
run \@cmd,
   \undef,
   '>pty>' => sub {
      $out .= $_[0];
      print $_[0];
   };

say "[$out]";
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to identify the buffering issue you mention, but my application hung using every solution I've tried until your '>pty>' solution, thank you!

Comment: Most apps buffer output to stdout as follows: If it's a terminal, flush on a line feed. Otherwise, flush when the buffer is full (4 Kib? 8Kib?). `>pty>` causes a pseudo-tty (i.e. a terminal) to be used, so that such an app will change its buffering behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that without any module using the "read from pipe" mode of [open](https://perldoc.pl/functions/open):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '-|', qw{ /usr/bin/tail -f /tmp/writetothis };

my $out;
while (<$in>) {
    $out .= $_;
    print;
    last if /^$/;  # Empty line to end the loop.
}
print $out;
```